# Where do I fix the asm error: ‘asm’ undeclared (first use in this function) in compiling gcc-7.2.0

Tags: gcc

I have been trying to install gcc-7.2.0. I am getting the same error on both ubuntu and on centos 6.7.The posts I have seen suggest changing the CFLAGS from -std=c99 to -std=gnu99. But I cannot figure out in which file I have to change this. The same error occurs on several lines, starting at line 55 of the file gcc_7_2_0_release/libgcc/config/i386/sfp-exceptions.c.
The error is

```
gcc_7_2_0_release/libgcc/config/i386/sfp-exceptions.c: In function ‘__sfp_handle_exceptions’:
gcc_7_2_0_release/libgcc/config/i386/sfp-exceptions.c:55:7: error: ‘asm’ undeclared (first use in this function)
asm volatile ("fdiv\t{%y0, %0|%0, %y0}" : "+t" (f));
```

Help will be appreciated please
gcc- v gives the following long extract:

```
 "Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man
--infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla
--enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch=i686 --build=i686-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18) (GCC)
```

I had to put this as an edit because it is too long for a comment

Comment: If you run 'gcc -v' what output do you see?

Comment: Taking a cue from Igor R, I did "gcc -v" on ubuntu where gcc-7 installs correctly, thanks to "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/gcc-7.1, sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get install gcc-7 g++-7". I used the output of gcc -v from this installed version in installation on Centos. The asm error disappears but other errors appear. After correcting error after error am stuck at "configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile" I have tried installing gmp, mpc, mpfr and isl independently from source, no success. Still struggling

Comment: From here https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gn u-toolchain/issues/134, this is how I got gcc-7.2.0 to build an install /configure --with-xlen=32 --prefix=/usr --disable-float --disable-atomic. Thanks to all who took time to look at my problem